# ReactPHP blocking process in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, websocket, reactphp

i am trying to make a websocket server in my wordpress plugin.

when i try to access the site it loads alot of time and outputs this iis error:

> The FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout

websocket server code:

```
$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$socket = new React\Socket\Server('127.0.0.1:9000', $loop);

$socket->on('connection', function (ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    $conn->write("Hello " . $conn->getRemoteAddress() . "!\n");

    $conn->on('data', function ($data) use ($conn) {
        $conn->close();
    });
});

$loop->run();
```

when i remove this code ^ it load fast and no error.

versions:

```
PHP: 7.2
ReactPHP: ^1.0 
Wordpress: 4.9.2
```

Comment: run it from cli, your not meant to init it from the browser.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone or everyone - is there a way to run it from wordpress?

Comment: its possible but you would need to track whether an instance is already running, then you just need to fire off an ajax request to start it, then close the connection, and then hopefully not open the client socket connection till its started.. much more hassle then simply running from cli.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey ReactPHP core maintainer here. Running any socket server including a websocket server is intended to run from the CLI or using supervisor/systemd. My suggestion would be to create such a special cli command in your plugin that you can call to start it. Doing funky magic with XHR requests is very error prone and not very stable. Alternatively if you absolutely cannot run cli commands is a service like pusher

Comment: For websockets my go to resource is Ratchet: https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet

Comment: is it possible to forward all requests to another remote websocket server?

Comment: You can in fact connect to any websocket server that allows you to connect to it. For exampole you can connect from lightx.net to wyrihaximus.net if my server allows it through headers and authentication.

Comment: Connect to `wss://www.wyrihaximus.net/` from the browser side :P

Comment: is it possible to set a custom events in RatchetPHP server?

Comment: Ratchet hands you a low level API to work with, you have to build your own communication protocol on top of that. You can also use the buildin support for WAMPv1 which gives you RPC and PubSub. Alternatively you can use Thruway for WAMPv2 but that is a whole different beast.

Comment: can i contact you personaly? im working on a project involving react and ratchet and i really need some help understanding a couple of things..

Comment: one of the questions i wanted to ask you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220769/php-websocket-forwarding-to-nodejs

Comment: Sure go ahead      .

Comment: how can i reach you?

Comment: Same username on twitter/github/freenode