# php websocket forwarding to nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, websocket, forwarding, ratchet

im tring to create an adapter in php to forward messages from javascript client to nodejs server and vice versa.

#### WebSockets:

nodejs server: [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws)

php server: [RatchetPHP](http://socketo.me)

php client: [RatchetPawl](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Pawl)

#### Code:

websocket server in php: [chatWSServer.php](https://github.com/neriyarosner/php-socket-forwarding/blob/master/chatWSServer.php)

connection class: [connection.php](https://github.com/neriyarosner/php-socket-forwarding/blob/master/inc/connection.php)

javascript client:

```
connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9000');
connection.onmessage = (e) => {
    console.log(e.data);
}
connection.onopen = (e) => {
    console.log("connection established!");
}
connection.addEventListener('message', (resData) => {
    console.log("got message:", resData);
});
```

#### Problem:

i try to open a connection to the nodejs websocket server (localhost:8889),
on javscript client connection to php websocket server (localhost:9000):
**chatWSServer.php - createConnection()**
and its working, 
but when the javascript client try to send a message i get:

> Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.

i think its because ratchet pawl connector loop is running - when i comment: `loop->run()` the client is able to send messages.

Answer (score 0):

with the help from @WyriHaximus i managed to solve this.

ive created a ratchetpawl websocket client with the same loop as ratchet websocket server's loop. and now its non blocking!

see my repository for code solution.